# itemized mem/time usage in a slurm job

Tags: memory, time, hpc, slurm

I have a slurm job like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH -o %A.%N.out
#SBATCH -e %A.%N.err
#SBATCH --partition=compute
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH -n 16
#SBATCH --export=ALL
#SBATCH -t 1:00:00

cmd1 input1 > o1
cmd2 o1 > o2
cmd3 o2 > o3
```

With `sacct`, one can get the time and cpu usage for the whole job. I am also interested to get those info for `cmd1` and `cmd3` specifically. How can you do that? Will job step and `srun` help do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a separate entry on sacct per step.

If you run your commands with srun they will generate a step and each one will be monitored and have its own entry.

After this you will see in the sacct output one line for the whole job, one for the batch step, and one for each of the steps on the script (srun/mpirun commands)

Comment: I tried that in the very beginning. It doesn't quite work. do you need to specify any options for `srun` to make sure they run sequentially?

Comment: If you want to run sequential commands why are you requesting 16 tasks?

Comment: each command is multithreaded, but you wanna to run the 3 commands one by one.

Comment: Then you should ask for cpus instead of tasks. Use the -c flag instead of -n

Comment: I am a little confused about the -n and -c flag of the slurm. I saw some online tutorial mention `-n` as number of cores. would you mind explaining a little bit?

Comment: -n is the number of parallel tasks that srun will spawn. -c is the number of cores requested per task. I don't have access now to a slurm installation but take a look to the sbatch and srun man pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82348/discussion-between-rna-and-carles-fenoy).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time -v` to get advanced information about timing and resources used. Not that this refers to the binary `/usr/bin/time`, not the shell built-in `time`:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v ls /
bin   dev  home  lib64       media  opt   root  sbin  sys  usr
boot  etc  lib   lost+found  mnt    proc  run   srv   tmp  var
    Command being timed: "ls /"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 94%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 2136
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 126
    Voluntary context switches: 1
    Involuntary context switches: 1
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
```

You can prepend this to any command in your batch script.

Comment: thanks! `sacct` would be ideal as it is more nicely formatted. If that does not work, `time` is not bad.